# Push Notifications for Cordova failed to build

Tags: android, cordova

I tried my first cordova application in visual studio with gcm plugin and i use this plugin 
GCMPushPlugin

and i went to this url to get the json  file

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

and i put the generated file in android platforms/android folder

and when i build the aplication it gives me these errors
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOK67.png)

Comment: ur dependancy isnt resolved , why r u using NDK?

Comment: im using android sdk and poiting to ndk also in the paths of visual studio

Comment: but why ndk? any functionaiy depenadancy?

Comment: actually i remove ndk from visual studio and still the same errors appears to me !! but now 68 errors

Comment: do u hv internet connection ? it seems that ur dependancy isnt downloaded listed in gardle file

Comment: i have internet .. the first error comes from a line >>apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: ok tell me r u importing some project or u builded cordova from sratch?

Comment: it is from scratch